# Can I use the technology of this patent for a consumer product?

Tags: usa

In reference to the patent: [US5529301](https://www.google.com/patents/US5529301)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, this isn't an active patent. The legal status of this patent is "Patent expired on 06/25/2004 due to non-payment of maintenance fee". You cannot even buy the patent because its expired even if you resurrect it.

You can use this technology but you have to further check the similar type of innovation before you use it for a product, because there might be other relevant patents.

Comment: Even if the fees had been paid, the patent would have expired in 2014 so it can't even be revived at this point.